# Trouble getting Jekyll Themes served on local machine (could not find addressable...)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

Been playing around with Jekyll for a few days now, but haven't been having any lucky trying to get themes working on my local machine.

I've tried several different themes and am getting errors that seem to be pointing towards missing files??? I'm not entirely sure as I'm completely new to Ruby.

### What I've got installed

- ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]
- jekyll 3.4.3

### What commands I'm running

```
~ $ cd ~/jekyll-theme/
~ $ jekyll serve
```

### Error and Trace

> C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': Could not find addressable-2.4.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

```
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `map!'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `materialize'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:176:in `specs'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:235:in `specs_for'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:224:in `requested_specs'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:100:in `setup'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:36:in `require_from_bundler'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/exe/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/jekyll:22:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

### Attemps

I've tried issuing the following command:
`~ $ bundle exec jekyll serve`
resulting in the same error and trace

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't have `addressable` gem installed.
Run `gem install jekyll` once again to make sure all required dependencies get installed.

Or if you have a `Gemfile`, run `bundle install`

Comment: I see the `Gemfile` in each of the themes project directory. When I read the file it looks like a set of installation instructions? Am I heading the right direction with this? Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. After issuing the `bundle install` command, 6 `Gemfile` dependencies and 22 gems are now installed. After running `jekyll serve` the system still complained about the addressable version not matching what was in the `Gemfile`, is this something to be bothered with? Ultimately the error suggested using `bundle exec jekyll serve` which worked fine.

Comment: A `Gemfile` is a list of Ruby gems required by your App (or theme in this case.) Prepending `bundle exec` to your jekyll commands will tell it to use only those versions listed rather than getting confused with another version that may have been installed in your system.

Comment: Now that you've explained that and I take another look at the `GemFile` it makes a lot of sense. Thanks.